# python-docx - Word found unreadable content - creating hyperlinks

Tags: python, python-docx

This is as simple as I think it's possible to create a document with a hyperlink using python-docx:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.oxml.shared import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn

document = Document()
paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
part = paragraph.part
r_id = part.relate_to('https://www.google.com', 'hyperlink', is_external=True)
hyperlink = OxmlElement('w:hyperlink')
hyperlink.set(qn('r:id'), r_id)
new_run = OxmlElement('w:r')
rPr = OxmlElement('w:rPr')
# Create a new Run object and add the hyperlink into it
new_run.append(rPr)
new_text = OxmlElement('w:t')
new_text.text = 'Google'
new_run.append(new_text)
hyperlink.append(new_run)
paragraph._p.append(hyperlink)
document.save('my-doc.docx')
```

When I try to open the saved file in Word, I get an error saying "Word found unreadable content in my-doc.docx"